# Regex to append before SQL FROM

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to append *before* the `FROM` in a SQL Query the following:

```
'' AS empImg
```

The select query could look like any number of things:

```
SELECT top 20 * FROM PERS_DAT
SELECT * FROM PERS_DAT
SELECT something1, something2 AS bob, something3 FROM PERS_DAT
SELECT top 20 something1, something2, something3 AS bob FROM PERS_DAT
etc etc..
```

Using Regex, how can I append **'' AS empImg** before the **FROM** clause in the query examples above?

example:

```
SELECT something1, something2 AS bob, something3, '' AS empImg FROM PERS_DAT
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Why you want regex? you can just replace "FROM" to " '' AS empImg " using VB code..

Comment: `/ [fF][rR][oO][mM] ` will find you ` FROM `. When found replace it with `'' AS empImg FROM `

Comment: What about `SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 aField FROM anotherTable) As C1 FROM PERS_DAT`? and any other nested inner selects or ... - I can say don't use a regex for this because it is so hard to find the main `FROM` from a SQL query ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a way to do it:

```
Dim thevalue As String = "SELECT top 20 something1, something2, something3 AS bob FROM PERS_DAT"
Dim sqlQueryAdd As String = Regex.Replace(thevalue, " [fF][rR][oO][mM] ", ", '' AS empImg $0")
```

Seems to give me:

```
SELECT top 20 something1, something2, something3 AS bob, '' AS empImg  FROM PERS_DAT
```

Comment: I would add a space after `" FROM"` to be sure

Comment: Good suggestion, @cha. Done in my OP.

Comment: and what if your `FROM` is written as `from` in the SQL script?

Comment: Using your suggestion @cha I placed the **[fF][rR][oO][mM]** in place of the " FROM" in my answer.

Comment: That is great! I do not want to disappoint you, but SQL Server is famous for its UPDATE ... FROM statement. How are you going to deal with it?

Comment: Currently I can control the syntax of the query from the user (they have a GUI that builds the query for them) They are only allow to make a SELECT query.